# Problem with export_savedmodel in Tensorflow v1.12.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-estimator

I am trying to use the *export_savedmodel* function to write an Estimator created from a Keras model. My code looks something like this:

```
from tensorflow.python import keras
...

model = keras.Model(...)
model.compile(...)
model.fit(...)
estimator_model = keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(keras_model=model, model_dir='./estimator_model')
estimator_model.export_savedmodel('./export', serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_fn)

def serving_input_fn():
    ...
```

I wrote this based on the [Google tutorial](https://www.kaggle.com/yufengg/emnist-gpu-keras-to-tf), but there were problems. Unfortunately, *export_savedmodel* can not find a trained model in *./estimator_model*.This surprised me because firstly I did not see any problem related to this in the attached link, and secondly in *export_savedmodel* we have an additional *checkpoint_path* parameter, which was not used, but looks like it has an impact.
Because *model_to_estimator* saves data to the folder *./estimator_model/keras* I tried to use it in the following way:

```
    estimator_model.export_savedmodel('./export', serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_fn, checkpoint_path='./estimator_model/keras/keras_model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001')
```

But now I have:
"Data loss: not an sstable (bad magic number): maybe your file is in a different file format?"

What's going on here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try

```
from tensorflow.python import keras
...

model = keras.Model(...)
model.compile(...)
estimator_model = keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(keras_model=model, 
model_dir='./estimator_model')
estimator_model.train(...)
estimator_model.export_savedmodel('./export', 
serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_fn)
```

To see if that works?

This is likely a bug, I'd report it on github.

Comment: Now I have a bit strange behavior. Sometimes I get the error:
"tensorflow.python.training.basic_session_run_hooks.NanLossDuringTrainingError: NaN loss during training", but it did not occur when I used the **fit** function (I use a small number of dummy records, but still). And when the model works, I get a warning that legacy_init_op is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.